# cannt update a struct list when assigning values

Tags: c#, list, struct, syntax-error

I'm doing some visual recognition, and depend on .net 2.0.

My program is a lot larger but i got a problem updating a struct in a list.
My list struct looks like this

```
NameSpace MyProg
 {
 Public partial class MainForm : Form
   {
    struct box
    {
        public int Pixelstart;
        public int Pixelend;
        public int Pixelcenter;
    }
    List<box> boxDetect = new List<box>();
```

there are a few more variables in here, but its about above variables that cause a problem. A custom image scanning function has to do some complex things with this, and also finding the boxes depends on some exotic math.
Well that math works, but the way i like to store and work with the data in a list structure doesnt seam to work.

So in that function there is a routine that scans the image
And add some point if certain conditions are agreed on.
Then i have a boxTemp defined as

```
box boxTemp; // based upon the common struct box
if (condition == true) {boxTemp.Pixelstart = Xposition;}
if (condition == false)
  {boxTemp.Pixelend = Xposition;
   boxTemp.Pixelcenter = XHalfPosition;
   boxDetect.Add(boxTemp);
```

the last line boxDetect.add(boxTemp) results in a syntax error that wont compile Error message : "Use of unassigned local variable boxTemp"

I dont get it because i've set its datafields before i update the list what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: How much do you understand about the difference between structs and classes? (As a general rule, mutable structs are a really bad idea.) Also note that C# is case sensitive - `If` != `if`, and `add` != `Add`. A short but *complete* example would be useful, ideally following normal .NET naming conventions...

Comment: I don't get what your problem is in understanding this. You declare a variable - `box boxTempk`, and try to use it with out any initialization - in those "`If`s" (is this capitalization even legal?). Not sure how much clearer one can be.

Comment: Updated the question indeed had to be "if" small case and Add. I think visual studio does indeed raise an error because boxTemp might be empty. Although when i look at it above to me it seams clear its not empty (or i dont get this error ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
box boxTemp = new box();
```

Comment: Amazingly that works.. but now i feel a bit lost why did that solve it